# Compare 2 dynamic arraylist id ,field with json response

Tags: android, arraylist

- I am having 2 arraylist , arraylist are field from web-service
- I have to compare arraylist and find un-common value from both
- Arraylist is dynamic and changing continious
- What i have done is :

  ```
  for (int i = 0; i < arraylist.size(); i++) {

           for (int j = 0; j < arraylist1.size(); j++) {

                     if ((arraylist.get(i).get("alert_id")).equals(arraylist1.get(j).get("alert_id")))
          {
                    Log.e("Same", "faltu");
                              }
                              else {
                                  Log.e("not same", "not faltu");
                              }

                          }
                      }
  ```

value :

```
arraylist 1 = id=92
arraylist 2 =id1 92
arraylist 1 = id1=91
arraylist 2 =id1 91
arraylist 1 = id1=86
arraylist 2 =id1 86
arraylist 1 =id1=85
arraylist 2 =id1 85
arraylist 1 = id1=84
arraylist 2 =id1 84
arraylist 1 = id1=81
arraylist 2 =id1 81
arraylist 1 =id1=80
arraylist 2 =id1 80
arraylist 1 = id1=79
arraylist 2 =id1 79
```

Comment: What is your problem..?

Comment: i want to simply compare 2 arraylist and take uncomman value and store it in another arraylist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you had to loop the two arraylist and you had to check whether the values are equal (OR) not. If the values are not equal, then it has to be added in the separate list and before adding to the list make sure the last value it is checked till the last value in the inner loop. The below code describes the sample process,

```
ArrayList<String> unCommonList = new ArrayyList<String>();

        for (int i= 0; i<arraylist.size();i++) {
            for (int j= 0; j<arraylist1.size();j++) {
                    if (!arrayList.get(i).equal(arraylist1..get(j))) {
                  //Checking whether the last value in the list..
                    if (j == (arrayList1.Size() - 1)) {
                        unCommonList.add(arrayList.get(i));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: how u can add arraylist simply like this ?

Comment: Have u seen my question,, i want particular alert_id, from your answer how i can get alert_id

Answer (score 0):

/* Try this one */

```
ArrayList<Integer> arrayList=new ArrayList<>();
arrayList.add(1);
arrayList.add(2);
arrayList.add(3);
arrayList.add(4);
ArrayList<Integer> arrayListtwo=new ArrayList<>();
arrayListtwo.add(1);
arrayListtwo.add(3);
arrayListtwo.add(4);
arrayListtwo.add(6);

    for(int i=0;i<arrayList.size();i++){
        for(int j=0;i<arrayListtwo.size();j++){
            if(arrayListtwo.get(j).equals(arrayList.get(i))){
                Log.e("equal",""+arrayList.get(i));
            }else{
                Log.e("unequal",""+arrayList.get(i));
            }

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Integer> A1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
A1.add(1);
A1.add(6);
A1.add(3);
A1.add(9);
List<Integer> B1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
B1.add(3);
B1.add(6);
```

You should be better off calling remove(Object obj) with each element in the collection containing objects to be removed. This method removes the first instance of obj so if you want to remove all occurrences you will have to take care of that. If the object has been found and removed successfully it returns a true otherwise a false is returned.

Hope this is what you were looking for?

```
List<Integer> A1MinusB1 = new ArrayList<Integer>(A1);
    A1MinusB1.removeAll(B1);
```

And the result will be

```
Results:

1

9
```

Or

You can do this.

// Make the two lists

```
List<Integer> list1 = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4);
List<Integer> list2 = Arrays.asList(2, 3, 4, 6, 7);
// Prepare a union
List<Integer> union = new ArrayList<Integer>(list1);
union.addAll(list2);
// Prepare an intersection
List<Integer> intersection = new ArrayList<Integer>(list1);
intersection.retainAll(list2);
// Subtract the intersection from the union
union.removeAll(intersection);
// Print the result
for (Integer n : union) {
    System.out.println(n);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [HashMap.put()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#put%28K,%20V%29) method.

If it returns any value means a key value pair already exists. If it returns null means no Key-Value pair exists.

This is most efficient way to find duplicates.